# bmpFactoryOptions don't work, no idea why

Tags: android, sqlite, opencv, bitmap, blob

I use the following code to get a Blob back from my SQLite database and get back a bitmap. My problem is that the reconstructed bitmap is larger than the original picture (input). It seems that my BitmapFactory.Options isn't working, but I have no idea what is wrong, nor am I getting an error. What is wrong with this code?

```
byte[] blob = contact.getMP();
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmpFactoryOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
bmpFactoryOptions.inScaled = false;
bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight = 240;
bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth = 320;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bmpFactoryOptions);


try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/test5.png");                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I check the output my 320 x 240 picture is 427 x 320. I don't want to use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap because it messes up the quality.

Comment: Where are you using the options?  I don't see it anywhere in this code.

Comment: it should be used on the blob which is changed to a bitmap (last line of the code).

Comment: But you're not passing the options in as an argument. Blackbelt has shown the correct signature. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream, android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass to `decodeStream` in order to work

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bmpFactoryOptions);
```

Comment: Oke I changed it, but it still didn't work, my input image (320 x 240) still comes out as a 427 * 320 image... I have no idea why

Comment: yes cause you are using it in the wrong way. outWidht and outHeight are filled by decodeStream. You can not fill with some value and hope the system will scale your bitmaps with those. that`s the difference betwen in* and out* field of Options. For scaling purpose  I suggest you to take a look to inSampleSize

Comment: Looked into it, but it works with powers of 2, so if i set `bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 2;` it comes back as a 213 x 160 image, which is too small. Thank you for the suggestion anyway, I'll keep looking into other options

Comment: I found it, and it was quite simple, but it has to be one of those things you 'need to know'. I just needed to put my pictures from the drawable-hdpi folder to a drawable-nodpi folder.. now Android doesn't resize the images, and it works like a charm :D